# In React Native, how do you determine if an image is cached/prefetched?

Tags: react-native

I am caching a few images like:

```
Image.prefetch(`${remoteImageUrl}/100x100`)
Image.prefetch(`${remoteImageUrl}/800x800`)
Image.prefetch(`${remoteImageUrl}/1000x1000`)
```

While that is happening a component that wants to show the highest resolution version currently available may render.

```
if 1000 cached use 1000, 
elseif 800 cached use 800,  
elseif 100 cached use 100
```

How do I test "if 1000 is cached"?
I tried **.complete** this with no luck.

```
if (Image.prefetch(`${remoteImageUrl}/1000x1000`).complete) {}
```

How do you check the existence of a prefetched image in React Native?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like this is possible using the out of the box APIs.

First of all, `Image.prefetch` doesn't contain any other methods related to the prefetch cache.

Diving into the detail - on iOS, [`Image.prefetch`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/Image.ios.js#L330) calls the native [`RCTImageViewManager.prefetchImage`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/RCTImageViewManager.m#L68) method, which indirectly ends up loading the image and storing it in `RCTImageCache`. Since there are no bridged functions that access the image cache directly, you're somewhat out of luck.

However, you could work around it by wrapping your calls to `Image.prefetch` in a function that tracks which ones have completed:

```
// imagePrefetch.js

const prefetchedImages = {};

export function prefetchImage(url) {
  return Image.prefetch(url)
    .then(val => {
      prefetchedImages[url] = true;
      return val;
    });
};

export function isPrefetched(url) {
  return prefetchedImages[url] !== undefined;
}
```

Keep in mind that this is specifically a workaround for images you *prefetch*, not other images that happened to be cached from being loaded through other means.